# How to replace all "string" type by "char" type in a cell array?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, type-conversion, cell-array

## Context

In R2016b, MATLAB introduced a new [string](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) datatype, in addition to the usual [char](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) datatype. So far, so good, but it is now giving me a lot of issues with the [JSONlab](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files) toolbox I'm using.

For instance, in R2015b, `loadjson` returns a 1x3 cell **character** array:

```
dd = loadjson('["Titi", "Toto", "Tata"]')

dd = 

    'Titi'    'Toto'    'Tata'
```

But in R2018a, `loadjson` returns a 1x3 **string** array:

```
dd = loadjson('["Titi", "Toto", "Tata"]')

dd =

  1×3 cell array

    {["Titi"]}    {["Toto"]}    {["Tata"]}
```

## Problem

For not having to change my code everywhere, I'd like to patch the `loadjson` routine to replace all `string` types it may return with `char` types. For instance, in the following cell array:

```
test = { 'hello', "world", 0.3; 'how', 'are', "you"}

test =

  2×3 cell array

    {'hello'}    {["world"]}    {[0.3000]}
    {'how'  }    {'are'    }    {["you" ]}
```

I'd like to replace all strings:

```
cellfun(@isstring, test)

ans =

  2×3 logical array

   0   1   0
   0   0   1
```

Is there a way I can do it quickly (i.e. without looping through all elements) ?

PS: I know of [jsondecode](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsondecode.html) and [jsonencode](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html) to replace JSONLab in the future, but so far I just want to quickly patch things.

Comment: The function `char` will convert to a character array.  Use `cellfun` or the like to apply it to an array and then use the logical index you have to replace.

Comment: `Titi` `Toto` is the new `foo` `bar`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `cellstr` (confusingly, despite "str" suggesting *string*) to convert strings to character arrays without looping or `cellfun`... the docs state the following:

> **`C = cellstr(A)` converts `A` to a cell array of character vectors**. The input array `A` can be a character array, a categorical array, or, starting in R2016b, a string array.

```
test = {'hello', "world", 0.3; 'how', 'are', "you"}; % multi-type test cell array
ind = cellfun(@isstring, test);                      % indexing for string type items
test(ind) = cellstr(test(ind))                       % char-ify the strings!
```

---

**A `cellfun` performance note for class checks:**

In both mine and Luis' answers, `cellfun` is used to determine which elements are strings. You can improve the performance of `cellfun` for this task...

Per the `cellfun` docs, there are some character array options which are much quicker than their function-handle counterparts. For the `isstring` indexing, it's likely a lot faster to run the first of these:

```
% rapid
ind = cellfun('isclass', test, 'string');
% akin to looping
ind = cellfun(@isstring, test);
```

They have the same output, in a simple test I see a 4x speed improvement:

```
% Create large test array of random strings
c = cell(100,1000);
c = cellfun(@(x) string(char(randi([65,122],1,10))), c, 'uni', 0);

% Create functions for benchmarking 
f=@()cellfun('isclass', c, 'string');
g=@()cellfun(@isstring,c);

% Timing on MATLAB R2017b
timeit( f ) % >> 0.017sec
timeit( g ) % >> 0.066sec
```

Comment: I already validated for @LuisMendo, but that's a good one too ! :)

Comment: @CitizenInsane Acceptance marks are never set in stone ;) In fairness some quick tests show that the `cellfun` option is approx. the same speed as `cellstr`, so the only advantage is readability.

Comment: Thanks for extra edit and deep inspection in speed improvement for checking if element is a `string` type ... you won :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `cellfun`,  but it has more or less the same performance as a loop:

```
test = {'hello', "world", 0.3; 'how', 'are', "you"};
ind = cellfun(@isstring, test);
test(ind) = cellfun(@char, test(ind), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: Damned, I was close to it, but was lost in the `{}` and the `()` syntax ... thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

As of MATLAB R2017b you can use [convertstringstochars](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convertstringstochars.html):

```
[test{:}] = convertStringsToChars(test{:});
```

Comment: I removed the typo additional spaces and tested this on R2017b, it works as expected (nicely leaves numeric elements as numeric too without complaint)

Answer (score 8):

Another solution, [discussed in the UndocumentedMATLAB blog](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/string-char-compatibility), is the "semi-documented" function of `controllib.internal.util.hString2Char`. This is how you use it:

```
test = { 'hello', "world", 0.3; 'how', 'are', "you"};
fixed_test = controllib.internal.util.hString2Char(test);

fixed_test =

  2×3 cell array

    {'hello'}    {'world'}    {[0.3000]}
    {'how'  }    {'are'  }    {'you'   }
```

According to the blog post, this function goes **recursively** through the input, so it works even in a situation like this:

```
test = {"target1", struct('field',{123,'456',"789"})};
ft = controllib.internal.util.hString2Char(test);
{ft{2}.field}

ans =

  1×3 cell array

    {[123]}    {'456'}    {'789'}
```

Take a look at the blog post for some caveats.

Comment: I would never have thought of so many good and various answer to just converting string to char ! :)

Comment: @CitizenInsane growing pains from the introduction of a new data class to a decades-old language :)